# Can't find language option on TYPO3 10.4

Tags: typo3-10.x

Recently we decided to upgrade our site from TYPO3 9.5 to TYPO3 10.4. We installed a fresh TYPO3 installation. But after installation when I am trying to set language option, I cannot find it under web > list. See the attached images. Can anyone please let me know if I am missing something?

Thanks in advance.
[image: TYPO3 10 List view]
[image: TYPO3 9 List view]
Regards
Prasun

Comment: You wrote "attached images" but there is no attached image.

Comment: Did you configure the languages in the "Site configuration"? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html

Comment: Ok. Added images. You can see there is no add language option as it was under Typo3 9

Comment: What about the + button?

Comment: That's really silly! It's working now.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Didn't realize the + button to add language

Comment: You probably aren't the first and the last. It happens. Good to hear it is now ok.

Answer (score 0):

Because I struggled for a couple of hours too:

1. A language for a typo3 site can be added by going to the `List` of database records on the left hand site.
2. Then select the site (Item called either `veniceXplorer` or `New Typo3 site` according to the screenshots in the question).
3. A `+` Icon with tooltip `Create new record` is in the middle at the top. Click on it.
4. `New Record` view appears. Under `System Records` there is an entry `Website Language`. Click on it.
5. Now a view `Create New Website Language on root level` appears. Type a name, select the language and a flag for it.
6. When done, press `Save`.
7. Now go to `Sites` on the left hand site
8. Press `edit` icon at your site
9. For each language put something meaningful into locale box
10. When done press `Save`

Now for your paragraphs you can select the new language.